# Quasar QDrawer component - prevent close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

It is possible to prevent closing drawer if user has unfinished work in it? So I can popup confirmation, etc..?

I was looking for some input like `can-be-closed="canBeClosed"`, then I look into dialog component which has its similarities. I did found `no-backdrop-dismiss` attribute, but it wasn't implemented on drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as its visibility is driven by input `value` you can use :value/@input combo instead of v-model and put custom logic in between.

```
<q-drawer
      :value="showDrawer"
      side="right"
      @input="logicShowDrawer"
    >
```

in logicShowDrawer you can decide whether you set prop showDrawer to true or not